# Why does trait resolution fail in this case?

Tags: rust

I thought Rust had orphan rules, etc. so that trait resolution is unambiguous. However, in this case, compilation fails, because the first instance (`&'a T`) is selected. If that instance is deleted, then the remaining instance (`&'a mut T`) is selected and works. So why is rustc unable to select the second instance in the presence of the first? Is there anything I can do about it? I'd like inference to work, not to hardcode the selection.

- [failing playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6799a20e16de100de7a4239761f3bb0a)
- [succeeding playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f83ff1643e8e5a9e6fa1f8a445da8c12)

```
use core::ops::Deref;

trait RefTaker<T> where Self: Deref<Target=T> + Sized {
    fn take_ref(self) -> Self { self }
}

impl<'a, T> RefTaker<T> for &'a T { }

impl<'a, T> RefTaker<T> for &'a mut T { }

fn main() {
    let mut x = 3u8;
    let _: &mut u8 = x.take_ref();
}
```

Comment: nit: ` where Self` is completely redundant here especially since you write it all in one line anyways

Answer (score 2):

From [method-call expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) in the Rust Reference:

> When looking up a method call, the receiver may be automatically dereferenced or borrowed in order to call a method. This requires a more complex lookup process than for other functions, since there may be a number of possible methods to call. The following procedure is used:
>
> The first step is to build a list of candidate receiver types. Obtain these by repeatedly dereferencing the receiver expression's type, adding each type encountered to the list, then finally attempting an unsized coercion at the end, and adding the result type if that is successful. **Then, for each candidate `T`, add `&T` and `&mut T` to the list** immediately after `T`.
>
> ...
>
> Note: the lookup is done for each type **in order**, which can occasionally lead to surprising results. The below code will print "In trait impl!", because `&self` methods are looked up first, the trait method is found before the struct's `&mut self` method is found.
>
> ```
> struct Foo {}
>
> trait Bar {
>   fn bar(&self);
> }
>
> impl Foo {
>   fn bar(&mut self) {
>     println!("In struct impl!")
>   }
> }
>
> impl Bar for Foo {
>   fn bar(&self) {
>     println!("In trait impl!")
>   }
> }
>
> fn main() {
>   let mut f = Foo{};
>   f.bar();
> }
> ```

So the implementation on `&u8` is checked before `&mut u8`, and it is a valid invocation, so it is accepted. Compilation proceeds and only fails later during type-checking and the compiler doesn't backtrack to try method resolution again.